# Get Currency Code From Culture Info(en-IN)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

How to get Currency Code 356 for the culture info (en-IN) .
I used the following API to get currency code, but it returns INR, but i need 356 as currency code.

```
-(NSString*)currencyCode
{
   NSLocale *lcl = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-IN"];
   NSNumberFormatter *fmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   [fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
   [fmtr setLocale:lcl];
   NSLog(@"%@",[fmtr currencyCode]);
   return [fmtr currencyCode];
}
```

Please suggest solution for this?

Comment: What you are really asking is now to map an ISO 4217 currency code to a currency number.  Why not simply hardcode this mapping into your app source code or via a `.plist` or something?

Comment: I will receive Culture info dynamically, so i have to change my currency code based on culture info, so i won't hardcode.

Comment: Why?  That mapping is set-in-stone and won't change.